# Tightness of probability measures and their second moments.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, means

Consider a sequence of probability densities on $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $\{\mu_n\}\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I am interested in showing that this sequence is tight, and I would like to know if there is a sufficient condition on the second moments

$$ M(\mu_n):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x^2 \mu_n(x)dx $$

which guarantees tightness.

Comment: Why are you interested in this condition on the second moment? Is there any application you have in mind?

Comment: Obviously $\sup_{n\ge1}M(\mu_n)<\infty$ implies tightness. (In fact, uniform boundedness of the first moment suffices.)

Comment: @ArcticChar a condition on any moment is what im interested in, since Im  more comfortable working with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second moments being (uniformly) bounded suffices by the Markov inequality.

Edit: as Nejimban commented, the weaker condition that the first absolute moments are bounded suffices.

Comment: Is there a weaker condition than uniform bounded moments?

Comment: Not without further conditions on the sequence of probability densities. For any sequence of (positive) second moments which is not bounded, I can give you a sequence of probability densities which is not tight, but has exactly the given sequence of second moments.

Comment: Another sufficient condition is $\sup_{n\ge1}\int f(x)\mathrm d\mu_n(x)<\infty$ where $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ is any measurable function such that $f(x)\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$ (possibly slower than $x^2$ or $|x|$). Same proof using Markov's inequality. By analogy with De la Vallée Poussin's criterion on uniform integrability, I'm guessing this is also a necessary condition.